# How to split this String using Regex Java

Tags: java, regex, split

As the title says I want to split a string specifically but I don´t know what to put inside the String.split("regex")

Say we have:

```
String s = "sum := A+B*( 99.1 +.44 444 1234+++)-sum/232.123459"
```

Now I want to split it to put it this way:

```
String[] splitted = ["sum"; ":="; "A"; "+"; "B"; "*"; "("; "99.1"; "+"; ".44"; "444"; "1234"; "+"; "+"; "+"; ")"; "-"; "sum"; "/"; "232.123459"]
```

So, basically I want to split by space, words, the math operators, numbers, the parenthesis, the letters and the number ".44" has to remain this way.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, and, what have you tried? Try creating a `Pattern` and then use `Matcher.find` instead. There is often nothing to use as separator in your string, so that will be tricky to find and use for `split`. Besides that, for expressions,  you should really use a parser, not a regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `split()`. Use a `find()` loop.

```
String regex = "[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*" + // Match number (e.g. 999 or 999.99)
              "|\\.[0-9]+" +        // Match number (e.g. .999)
              "|[a-zA-Z]\\w*" +     // Match identifier
              "|:=" +  // Match complex operator
              "|\\S";  // Match other single non-space, incl. operators: +, -, *, /, (, )
```

*Test*

```
String s = "sum := A+B*( 99.1 +.44 444 1234+++)-sum/232.123459";
String[] splitted  = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
```

*Output*

```
[sum, :=, A, +, B, *, (, 99.1, +, .44, 444, 1234, +, +, +, ), -, sum, /, 232.123459]
```